# how to select only one check box in List view with multiple check box in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

i am used in two check box  in listview for first colunm checkbox worked second column checkbox1 not worked in the list view only one at a time select

click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4x6E.jpg) to see screenshot

```
    i tried this code please help me
```

i tried this code please help me

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend> {
        private List<Friend> myFriends;
        private Activity activity;
        private int selectedPosition = -1;

        public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<Friend> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);

            this.activity = context;
            this.myFriends = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            // If holder not exist then locate all view from UI file.
            if (convertView == null) {
                // inflate UI from XML file
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, parent, false);
                // get all UI view
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                // set tag for holder
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                // if holder created, get tag from view
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.checkBox.setTag(position); 
             holder.checkBox1.setTag(position+1); 

            holder.friendName.setText(getItem(position).getName());


            if (position == selectedPosition) {
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
            } else holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

            if(holder.checkBox.getTag().equals(position){
    holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(onStateChangedListener(holder.checkBox, position));
    }else{
    holder.checkBox1.setOnClickListener(onStateChangedListener(holder.checkBox1, position));
    }

            return convertView;
        }

        private View.OnClickListener onStateChangedListener(final CheckBox checkBox, final int position) {
            return new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                        selectedPosition = position;
                    } else {
                        selectedPosition = -1;
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };
        }

        private static class ViewHolder {
            private TextView friendName;
            private CheckBox checkBox,checkBox1;

            public ViewHolder(View v) {
                checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.check);
                checkBox1 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.check1);
                friendName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            }
        }
```

also can't call the this onStateChangedListener  method every time first column check box worked fine but else part not working control does't go here holder.checkBox1.getTag() holder.checkBox1.setOnClickListener(onStateChangedListener(holder.checkBox1, position));

```
In the hole list view only one checkbox should select how will achive this any one please help me
```

Comment: This question is very difficult to understand. Please try to clarify exactly what is happening, and what you want to happen.

Comment: Please explain your question clearly.

Comment: i have two check box horizontally. select only one at a time for both horizontally or vertically

Comment: Do you mean that,suppose you have 10 rows in your list view, each having 2 checkboxes say `checkbox1` and `checkbox2`. Then when you click a `checkbox1` of say row 5, then all `checkbox1` from other rows must be deselected? and same with `checkbox2`?

Comment: yes exactly If i selected Row 5 checkbox 1 all other checkbox unselect including checkbox 2

Comment: confused man..  you have two checkbox columns where you want to be selected only 1 check box from both columns or from each column only 1 is to be selected.????

Comment: see  i have two checkbox in a row CheckBOX1,CheckBOX2, for example i have 10 rows means 20 checkbox.  out of 20 checkbox i select any one of check box. all other (19) should unselect

Answer (score 0):

Make the tag of the checkbox a string that contains both the position in the list and the id of the box.
I frequently use the `string.split()`

Example:

```
holder.checkbox.setTag(checkboxid + ";" + position);
```

Then, when getting the tag:

```
String[] tag = v.getTag().toString().split(";);
```

where

- tag[0] = the id of the checkbox
- tag[1] = the position in the list

Comment: i have doubt.i am using two chek box but only one select for more than one row i.e,Vertically(datas ) and horizontaly(i.e checkbox 1,checkbox2)